# Show Errors in modal ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm new to ajax and I want to display the errors in my modal. i'm using laravel

This is my blade

**> add-store.blade.php**

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addBtn">+Add a new Store</button>
    <div id="addBtn" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add A New Store</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-10">Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-10">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">
                            <p class="error text-center alert alert-danger hidden">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-10">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-10">Designate Store</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="store_id" id="store_id">
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal" id="save">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script at the end of page

```
<script>
    var urlAdd = '{{ route('addSocialWorker') }}';
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';

    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlAdd,
            data: {
                'name': $('#name').val(),
                'email': $('#email').val(),
                'password': $('#password').val(),
                'store_id': $("#store_id").val(),
                '_token': token
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if ((data.errors)) {
                    console.log(data);
                } else {
                    $('#usersTable').append(data);
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

AdminController.php

```
public function addSocialWorker(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4',
        'store_id' => 'required|numeric',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json([
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray(),
        ]);
    } else {
        $data = new User();
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->email = $request->email;
        $data->password = $request->password;
        $data->status = 1;
        $data->role_id = 2;
        $data->store_id = $request->store_id;
        $data->save();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

with the validation above. I'm really new to ajax and jquery. Do you have ideas how to display the errors in the modal?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Yeah, I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can clean your controller up quite a bit:

```
public function addSocialWorker(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4',
        'store_id' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $data = new User();
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->password = $request->password;
    $data->status = 1;
    $data->role_id = 2;
    $data->store_id = $request->store_id;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

With the above you won't have to manually check if the validation passes or not, it will also send the response with the correct HTTP status (422).

You'll need to add an `error` method to your ajax call so that you can actually catch the error as `success` will not be called on error.

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#usersTable').append(data);
},
error: function (res) {

    if (res.status == 422) {
        var data = res.responseJSON;

        for (let i in data) {
            console.log(i, data[i][0])
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to show the errors you could something like:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-name">
        <label class="control-label mb-10">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe">
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-email">
        <label class="control-label mb-10">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">
        <span class="help-block"></span>
        <p class="error text-center alert alert-danger hidden">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-password">
        <label class="control-label mb-10">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"
               placeholder="">
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-store_id">
        <label class="control-label mb-10">Designate Store</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="store_id" id="store_id">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

//

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function showValidationErrors(name, error) {

            var group = $("#form-group-" + name);
            group.addClass('has-error');
            group.find('.help-block').text(error);
        }

        function clearValidationError(name) {
            var group = $("#form-group-" + name);
            group.removeClass('has-error');
            group.find('.help-block').text('');
        }

        $("#name, #email, #password").on('keyup', function () {
            clearValidationError($(this).attr('id').replace('#', ''))
        });
        $("#store_id").on('change', function () {
            clearValidationError($(this).attr('id').replace('#', ''))
        });

        $("#save").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('addSocialWorker') }}',
                data: {
                    'name': $('#name').val(),
                    'email': $('#email').val(),
                    'password': $('#password').val(),
                    'store_id': $("#store_id").val(),
                    '_token': '{{ Session::token() }}'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data, 'I am the success method')
                },
                error: function (res) {

                    if (res.status == 422) {
                        var data = res.responseJSON;

                        for (let i in data) {
                            showValidationErrors(i, data[i][0])
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: my modal still closes

Comment: modal still closes how to do it sir?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create class in your modal-body - let's call it errors, and place it on the very bottom in modal-body. This is where your errors will apear.

```
<div class="errors"></div>
```

If the data is **sent correctly** from your controller, then you need to loop in **each error** (in your success function). (alert alert-danger classes are bootstrap classes, you can remove it)

```
for (var i in data) {

  $('errors').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data[i].error_text+'</div>');

}
```

The error_text can be **versatile**, it depends what's returned in your data response. You can check it out by using **console.log(data)**.

Comment: Where would I put this? still the modal closes and not displays

Comment: @A.Sand it won't show as success won't be called when there's an error response.

Comment: @RossWilson the success method is called when the respond from controller was sent correctly, so don't tell me that it won't be called.

Comment: After i clicked and i inputted a wrong input, The modal still closes

Comment: I can't still get the errors to display in my modal

Comment: @forexknight Oh right, I didn't know that. According to the Laravel docs when validations fails it should return a 422 status code (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields under the heading **AJAX Requests & Validation**) and I was under the impression that the `$.ajax` `success` method should only be called when 2** or 304 status code is returned (from the code base : `isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;` https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js line 736). How should I be sending the respond from controller correctly? :)

Comment: I'm doing it like this: `return response()->json(['data' => $data],200);`

Comment: Sirs, I'm still not getting the idea. I'm very sorry Can you share some of your codes?

Comment: @forexknight For validation?!?

Comment: @RossWilson Of course not for validation. I just showed how I return data from controller to js by ajax.

Comment: @forexknight Just have another look through these comments, dude. We were originally talking about validation errors, haha. Either way, have a nice day, man. :) Also, just FYI, the `200` isn't necessary as it's the default value and you could do `return compact('data');` and receive the exact same response.

Comment: @RossWilson Yea, sorry dude. I have a lot of work, that's why my reply was so bad.